# Inserting values into a list whilst looping over it (Python)

Tags: python, string, list, insert

I have the following list of lists:

```
sweet = [['1234-4321-1',[5, 6, -4, 11, 22]], ['1234-7834-1', [43, -5, 0, 0, -1]], ['1234-5376-1', [3, 0, -5, -6, 0]], ['1567-3454-1', [4, 6, 8, 3, 3]], ['1567-9987-1-', [1, 2, 1, -4, 5]]]
```

I wish to iterate over the list of lists and separate the different groups of sublists by the # character i.e. I wish the # to be inserted when the first element of the sublists string changes.

desired result

```
>>sweet
>>[['1234-4321-1',[5, 6, -4, 11, 22]], ['1234-7834-1', [43, -5, 0, 0, -1]], ['1234-5376-1', [3, 0, -5, -6, 0]], '#', ['1567-3454-1', [4, 6, 8, 3, 3]], ['1567-9987-1-', [1, 2, 1, -4, 5]]]
```

Trivial task perhaps but I am very new to Python, help much appreciated.

EDIT

I am awaret hat perhaps a dictionary now would be a better data structure and hence the '#' key may not be needed, I was aiming to use it as a separtor of the stations (first number in the string) so that I could do computations of the stations in isolation whilst iterating over the list.

My goal you see is to iterate over the list (should make it a dictionary) and compute the difference between pairs of lists of ints within each important first number.    Desired final result looking like: {'1234': [[-38, 11, -4, 11, 23], [40, -5, 5, 6, -1]] '1567':[[3, 4, 7, 11, -2]] }

Any help on this also much appreciated :)

Comment: FYI, you're probably going to be asked the age old question; "What have you tried?"

Comment: Are you sure it's the best way to organize your data?

Comment: @jamylak it is the way I have received the data, not the way I have chosen to organize it. I wish to cycle over all the data and perform a subtraction of pairs of branches within each station, the station being represented by the first segment of the string, so I though it would be a good idea to separate the stations with a flag of some kind i.e. the '#' so that I did not end up doing computations of values from two different stations.

Comment: @user1532369 Separating into groups using `list`s or `groupby` could probably do the job without use of `'#'`.

Comment: @jamylak do you think a dictionary structure (such as that 2 answers below) would be more efficient for doing computations whilst iterating over these values rather that the list format?

Comment: @jamylak my goal you see is to iterate over these and compute the difference between pairs of lists of int within each important first number.    Ideal final result looking like: {'1234': [[-38, 11, -4, 11, 23], [40, -5, 5, 6, -1]] '1567':[[3, 4, 7, 11, -2]] }

Comment: @user1532369 if you are iterating in order through the items each time you only need a list.

Comment: @jamylak that's true, however a dict/list structure is definitely more maintainable and easier to insert values.  Also this example assumes a sorted list, the dictionary removes that requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your data would be better organized as a dictionary.  Like so:

```
sweet = {'1234-4321-1': [5, 6, -4, 11, 22], 
         '1234-7834-1': [43, -5, 0, 0, -1],
         '1234-5376-1': [3, 0, -5, -6, 0],
         '1567-3454-1': [4, 6, 8, 3, 3],
         '1567-9987-1': [1, 2, 1, -4, 5] }
```

You could then access elements by *key* as in `sweet['1234-4321-1']` which would return your first list.

Or since the first number seems to be the key element to split by, something a little more complex:

```
sweet = {'1234': [['4321-1', [5, 6, -4, 11, 22]], 
                  ['7834-1', [43, -5, 0, 0, -1]],
                  ['5376-1', [3, 0, -5, -6, 0]]],
         '1567': [['3454-1', [4, 6, 8, 3, 3]],
                 ['9987-1', [1, 2, 1, -4, 5]]] 
        }
```

then saying `sweet['1234']` would give you a list of pairs that you could address by index.  `sweet['1234'][0]` gives the first entry in the list.

That being said, you could insert the '#' by doing something like:

```
sweet = [['1234-4321-1',[5, 6, -4, 11, 22]], ['1234-7834-1', [43, -5, 0, 0, -1]], ['1234-5376-1', [3, 0, -5, -6, 0]], ['1567-3454-1', [4, 6, 8, 3, 3]], ['1567-9987-1-', [1, 2, 1, -4, 5]]]

skip = False
for i in range(len(sweet)-1):
    if skip: #skip over the '#' that was just inserted
            skip = False
            continue
    front_num_1 = sweet[i][0].split('-')[0]
    front_num_2 = sweet[i+1][0].split('-')[0]
    if front_num_1 != front_num_2:
        sweet.insert(i+1, '#')
        skip = True

print sweet
```

but as everyone else has explained, this data structure seems weak.

Comment: this more complex dictionary seems absolutely ideal, any idea how I could reorganize my list to a dictionary form like this ?

Comment: I could probably even do with having it like this: sweet = {'1234': [[5, 6, -4, 11, 22], [43, -5, 0, 0, -1]], [3, 0, -5, -6, 0]], '1567':[[4, 6, 8, 3, 3], [1, 2, 1, -4, 5]] }

Comment: my goal you see is to iterate over these and compute the difference between pairs of lists of int within each important first number.    Ideal final result looking like: {'1234': [[-38, 11, -4, 11, 23], [40, -5, 5, 6, -1]] '1567':[[3, 4, 7, 11, -2]] }

Comment: the only thing I see wrong with you 'ideal final result' is that you didn't put a comma after  the first `]]` which is where you start the next dictionary entry.  So what you want is this `{'1234': [[-38, 11, -4, 11, 23], [40, -5, 5, 6, -1]], '1567':[[3, 4, 7, 11, -2]] }`  When you say the difference, you mean the mathematical difference, yes?

Comment: also, where do you want the difference to go?

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want, but not in an elegant way *(I'm new to python myself)*.

```
sweet = [['1234-4321-1',[5, 6, -4, 11, 22]], ['1234-7834-1', [43, -5, 0, 0, -1]], ['1234-5376-1', [3, 0, -5, -6, 0]], ['1567-3454-1', [4, 6, 8, 3, 3]], ['1567-9987-1-', [1, 2, 1, -4, 5]]]
ans=[]
j=sweet[0][0].split('-')[0]
for i in sweet:
    print i
    if i[0].split('-')[0]!=j:
        ans.append("#")
    ans.append(i)
    j=i[0].split('-')[0]
sweet=ans
```

Answer (score 1):

This accomplishes the task but I think your data structure is not well chosen.

```
new_sweet = sweet[0]
for s in sweet[1:]:
    if s[0].split('-')[0] != new_sweet[-1][0].split('-')[0]:
       new_sweet.append('#')
    new_sweet.append(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f = lambda l: l[0].split('-')[0]
indexes = (i for i in range(1, len(sweet)) if f(sweet[i]) != f(sweet[i-1]))
for i, j in enumerate(indexes):
    sweet.insert(i+j, '#')
```

Comment: Note: Probably won't matter in this case but this could be slow for huge lists due to `list.insert`.

Comment: my list is very large the above is just an excerpt

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby, chain
>>> def join(iterable, delimiter):
        i = iter(iterable)
        yield next(i)
        for el in i:
            yield delimiter
            yield el


>>> sweet = [['1234-4321-1',[5, 6, -4, 11, 22]], ['1234-7834-1', [43, -5, 0, 0, -1]], ['1234-5376-1', [3, 0, -5, -6, 0]], ['1567-3454-1', [4, 6, 8, 3, 3]], ['1567-9987-1-', [1, 2, 1, -4, 5]]]
>>> groups = (g for k, g in groupby(sweet, lambda x: x[0].partition('-')[0]))
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(join(groups, delimiter='#')))
[['1234-4321-1', [5, 6, -4, 11, 22]], ['1234-7834-1', [43, -5, 0, 0, -1]], ['1234-5376-1', [3, 0, -5, -6, 0]], '#', ['1567-3454-1', [4, 6, 8, 3, 3]], ['1567-9987-1-', [1, 2, 1, -4, 5]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for i in range(len(s)-1):
          a,b=s[i][0][:4], s[i+1][0][:4]
          if a!=b:
             s.insert(i+1,"#")
             break
```